# Compare embedded document to parent field with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider the following collection, where the parent document has a `amount` field with the value `100000` and there's an embedded array of documents with the same field `amount` and the same value.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5975ce5f05563b6303924914"),
  "amount" : 100000,
  "offers" : [ 
    {
      "amount": 100000
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to match all objects that has at least one embedded document `offer` with the same amount as the parent?

If I for example query this, it works just fine:

```
find({ offers: { $elemMatch: { loan_amount: 100000 } } })
```

But I don't know the actual value `100000` in the real query I'm trying to assemble, I would need to use a variable for the parent documents amount field. Something like this.

```
find({ offers: { $elemMatch: { loan_amount: "parent.loan_amount" } } })
```

Thankful for any suggestions. I was hoping to do this with `$eq` or `$elemMatch`, and to avoid aggregates, but maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard queries cannot "compare" values in documents. This is actually something you do using `.aggregate()` and [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$gt": [
          { "$size": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$offers",
              "as": "o",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$o.amount", "$amount" ] }
            }
          }},
          0
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

Here we use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to compare the values of `"amount"` in the parent document to those within the array. If at least one is "equal" then we `"$$KEEP"` the document, otherwise we `"$$PRUNE"`

In most recent versions, we can shorten that using [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$ne": [
          { "$indexOfArray": [ "$offers.amount", "$amount" ] },
          -1
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

If you actually only wanted the "matching array element(s)" as well, then you would add a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in projection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$gt": [
          { "$size": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$offers",
              "as": "o",
              "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$o.amount", "$amount" ] }
            }
          }},
          0
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "amount": 1,
    "offers": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$offers",
        "as": "o",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$o.amount", "$amount" ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

But the main principle is of course to "reduce" the number of documents returned to **only** those that actually match the condition as a "first" priority. Otherwise you are just doing unnecessary calculations and work that is taking time and resources, for results that you later would discard.

So "filter" first, and "reshape" second as a priority.

Comment: Thanks so much, would it have been easier if the offers document had their own collection with a reference to the other document. This aggregation seems like a lot of work, I mean performancewise, is it better to put the offer document in it's own collection and reference the other documents id?

Comment: @StefanKonno "Performance wise" putting things in another collection is **worse**. Joins cost, and dearly. This is why you "should" be using MongoDB in the first place. There is no "easy" way to compare one field to another. Any method has a cost, and this is true of relational databases as well.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll give it a try. I appreciate your effort, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I think since MongoDB version 3.6 you can actually do this with a simple filter using the [expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator.

Something along those lines:

```
find({
  $expr: {
    $in: [
      "$amount",
      "$offers.amount"
    ]
  }
})
```

See a live example on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5llcD8Dhy98)