# Have embedded documents instead of relying on foreign keys?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am new to MongoDB and NoSQL.  I actually have different follow up questions depending on how this question gets answered.  And I'll post my follow up questions as a separate question.  Here we go...

I am trying to model a database to help me answer a question such as "Find all departments where 2 (TWO) or more teams each have 2 (TWO) or more employees known to have caused accidents greater than their team's max_accidents."  If I were allowed to use a relational database with MySQL, I would solve the problem by making these tables:

```
department:department_id, location_id (FK to a location table not described here), unit_type

team: team_id, department_id, max_accidents

employee: employee_id, team_id, accidents
```

And then I'd use this query (untested, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
SELECT department_id FROM team
WHERE EXISTS (

    SELECT 1 FROM department
    WHERE department.department_id = team.team_id
    AND team.team_id IN (

        SELECT team_id FROM employee
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM team
            WHERE team.team_id = employee.team_id
            AND employee.accidents > team.max_accidents
        ) GROUP BY team_id HAVING COUNT(*) >=2

    )
) GROUP BY department_id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

From what I understand about NoSQL databases, I can see two ways to model my collections.  First, I could model each collection in exactly the same way I set out my tables above, meaning foreign keys would exist.  The second possible way is this:

```
department = {_id,teams:[]team};

team = {_id,max_accidents,employees:[]employee};

employee = {_id,accidents};
```

My guess is that I should use the second approach where I embed arrays of documents.  Then to perform my query, I would need to learn how to use the MongoDB aggregate framework as demonstrated in this question here:

[Compare embedded document to parent field with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412506/compare-embedded-document-to-parent-field-with-mongodb)

I can build upon the aggregate approach to implement my `HAVING COUNT(*)` behaviour by using the `$match` feature as demonstrated in this question here:

[What is the correct way to do a HAVING in a MongoDB GROUP BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550253/what-is-the-correct-way-to-do-a-having-in-a-mongodb-group-by)

I'd like confirmation if I'm approaching this problem correctly?  If not, would be great if someone could explain why I might be approaching it the wrong way or what I might need to concern myself with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MongoDB Documentation

> In general, use embedded data models when:
>
> - you have “contains” relationships between entities. See Model
>     One-to-One Relationships with Embedded Documents.
> - you have one-to-many
>     relationships between entities. In these relationships the “many” or
>     child documents always appear with or are viewed in the context of the
>     “one” or parent documents. See Model One-to-Many Relationships with
>     Embedded Documents.
>
> In general, embedding provides better performance
>   for read operations, as well as the ability to request and retrieve
>   related data in a single database operation. Embedded data models make
>   it possible to update related data in a single atomic write operation.

This is a fair enough guideline. However you can take you call depending on your case.

Ask questions:

- Can an employee be part of multiple teams ?
- Can a team be part of multiple departments ?

If answer is yes, would not think about embedded documents.

Consider a scenario where one employee is part of multiple teams. That means the employee object exists in multiple documents.

Which can cause: data duplication, need more storage, make updates redundant.

Comment: Thanks, here's my follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081371/mongodb-get-all-embedded-documents-where-condition-is-met