# MongoDB - Count unread messages

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I try to count unread messages for a user.

On my model, I have a property, `LastMessageDate` that contains the date on the last created message in the group chat. I have also a `Members` property (list) that contains the members in the group chat. Each member has the `UserId` and `LastReadDate` properties. The `LastReadDate` is updated when the user writes a new message in the group chat or when the user loads messages from the group chat.

Now I want to count the number of chats where a specific user has unread messages (The messages are stored in another collection).
I try this:

```cs
var db = GetGroupCollection();

var filter = Builders<ChatGroup>.Filter.Where(p => p.Members.Any(m => m.UserId == userId && m.LastReadDate < p.LastMessageDate));
return await db.CountDocumentsAsync(filter);
```

But I receive the following error:

> The LINQ expression: {document}{Members}.Where((({document}{UserId} ==
> 730ddbc7-5d03-4060-b9ef-2913d0b1d7db) AndAlso
> ({document}{LastReadDate} < {document}{LastMessageDate}))) has the
> member "p" which can not be used to build a correct MongoDB query.

What should I do? Is there a better solution?

Comment: As I know, currently it's not supported to use parent linq income argument (`p`) in nested linq queries, you can try a raw query in form like: `await db.CountDocumentsAsync("your query in a raw json/bson form ")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the provided data in the comment, I think the aggregation query is required to achieve the outcome.

1. `$set` - Set `Members` field

   1.1. `$filter` - With `Members` array as `input`, filter the document(s) with matching the current document's `UserId` and `LastMessageDate` is greater than (`$gt`) the current document's `LastReadDate`.
2. `$match` - Filter the document with `Members` is not an empty array.

```
db.groups.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      Members: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Members",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.UserId",
                  1
                ]
              },
              {
                $gt: [
                  "$LastMessageDate",
                  "$$this.LastReadDate"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      Members: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DLMsoJ_vat0)

---

For C# syntax, either you can directly provide the query as a string or convert the query to `BsonDocument` syntax.

Note that the query above will return the array of documents, hence you will need to use *System.Linq* to count the returned document(s).

```cs
using System.Linq;

var pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$set", 
        new BsonDocument("Members", 
            new BsonDocument("$filter", 
                new BsonDocument
                { 
                    { "input", "$Members" },
                    { "cond", new BsonDocument
                        (
                            "$and", new BsonArray
                            {
                                new BsonDocument("$eq", 
                                    new BsonArray { "$$this.UserId", userId }),
                                new BsonDocument("$gt",
                                    new BsonArray { "$LastMessageDate", "$$this.LastReadDate" })
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    ),
    new BsonDocument("$match",
        new BsonDocument("Members",
            new BsonDocument("$ne", new BsonArray())))

};

var db = GetGroupCollection();

return (await db.AggregateAsync<BsonDocument>(pipeline))
    .ToList()
    .Count;
```

Comment: thanks, works perfect. One thing, this query will return all matching documents to the c# code, then the c# code will count the items/list? If so, is it posible to return only the number of the items?

Comment: *this query will return all matching documents to the c# code, then the c# code will count the items/list?* Yes, the C# side does the counting. *If so, is it posible to return only the number of the items?* Did you mean MongoDB side to return count only? If yes, I afraid that it is not possible for MongoDB so far.

Comment: Performance-wise, since you are performing count, you return the document with `_id` field only and omit the rest field(s) via `$project` from MongoDB side.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to query a nested list of a document, ElemMatch is your solution,
Try

```
var filter = builder.ElemMatch(o => o.Members,m => m.UserId == userId && m.LastReadDate < p.LastMessageDate);
```

Comment: I can't access o.LastMessageDate, Error CS0103 The name 'o' does not exist in the current context

Comment: First parameter of the ElemMatch function accepts the members array, that's the o.
Second parameter is the lambda > m => m.UserId == userId && m.LastReadDate < p.LastMessageDate

Comment: Where do you get p in p.LastMessageDate from?

Comment: After taking another look, I think the problem is that you query a nested list based on a value on the document that holds it. when you ask for m.LastReadDate < p.LastMessageDate the m is the nested list item, and the p is the document that holds it. it is not possible with the solution I gave you.

Comment: Try using aggregation, you want to have the LastMessageDate field projected into the ElemMatch query, and then you will be able to use it. Take a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412506/compare-embedded-document-to-parent-field-with-mongodb

Comment: Thanx, i tried this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YkNGD86ucUO  but i can't get any result  :/  UserId 1 and 2 should return 1 each and userid 3 nothing.